# How to inspect the POST body in IBM Cloud Functions?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am running a few cloud functions now and want to see the payload (POST body) of the request that is handled by my cloud function.

The activation log "only" shows the response.

https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/dashboard

Should I log it myself in Java code of is there an option in the CLI to get this data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is not logged. You have two options. The first is to log it yourself as you noted. The second is to use a sequence and an echo action as the first component of the sequence. In general, a sequence will allow you to see the result of a previous action which is the input to the next in the composition.